# While running tensorboard command and i am getting error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

`!tensorboard --logdir=drive/My Drive/Proj/fer/checkpoint/logs/`

**i am running this command in google colab **

[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQhgw.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do not attach text as images. Instead, paste it as a quote or as code. Also please mention the type of error you get in the question title to make it helpful for others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because of the empty space in 'My Drive'. So you need to escape the whitespace or rename it:

```
!tensorboard --logdir=drive/My\ Drive/Proj/fer/checkpoint/logs/
```

Comment: Thx,  it worked for me but my browser cannot reach the link, it says unable to connect

Comment: http://localhost:6006/   this link is given by tensorborab which i cant open

Comment: It's unrelated to your previous issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

Comment: sure i'll ask a new ques